# xslt to flatten xml hierarchy using attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am searching for a solution to transform this XML :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <X id="aaa" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</X>
        <X id="bbb" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</X>
        <X id="ccc" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</X>
        ...
    </B>
    <C>
        <Y id="aaa" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</Y>
        <Y id="bbb" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</Y>
        <Y id="ccc" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</Y>
        ...
    </C>
    <D>
        <Z id="aaa" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</Z>
        <Z id="bbb" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</Z>
        <Z id="ccc" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</Z>
        ...
    </D>
    ...
</A>
```

into this:

```
<A>
    <B_X_aaa id="aaa" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</B_X_aaa>
    <B_X_bbb id="bbb" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</B_X_bbb>
    <B_X_ccc id="ccc" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</B_X_ccc>
    <C_Y_aaa id="aaa" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</C_Y_aaa>
    <C_Y_bbb id="bbb" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</C_Y_bbb>
    <C_Y_ccc id="ccc" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</C_Y_ccc>
    <D_Z_aaa id="aaa" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</D_Z_aaa>
    <D_Z_bbb id="bbb" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</D_Z_bbb>
    <D_Z_ccc id="ccc" text="xyz" unit="mm">asdf</D_Z_ccc>
</A>
```

So the last part of the transformed xml node name has to be the 'id' attribute value and the attributes have to be copied all

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/A">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
            <xsl:element name="{name(..)}_{name()}_{@id}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```